# Asp Net Boilerplate - Setup Schema-Per-Tenant Multitenancy (EntityFrameworkCore & PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, sass, multi-tenant, aspnetboilerplate

We are looking into using Asp Net Boilerplate. Looks very promising. We love the framework, but we would like to be able to use a per-schema Multitenancy configuration. Instead of sharing the data in the same db & tables, each tenant would "have" a schema, in which the whole database structure would be replicated.

One of our data tables will be quite big (sometimes +1 million entries / tenant), and we were advised that for performance reasons, it's better to keep the number of entries as low as possible. Also, this particular table will be queried & inserted a lot. It would be unrealistic that this table would hold data for 40+ tenants. For that reason, and others, we would prefer to have a distinct schema per tenant.

Our DB is a single PostgreSQL server (might scale up to more in the future). We use EntityFramework & Npgsql. We already noticed that it is possible to set up a different ConnectionString for specific tenants that would have bigger data requirements.

http://www.summa.com/blog/2013/09/17/approaches-to-multi-tenancy See separate schema per tenant

Any idea on how to acheive a schema-per-tenant multitenancy? There's a lot of moving parts in this, I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Do tenants not share the same schema (DbContext) definition?

Comment: By schema I meant PostgreSQL schemas (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html).

Comment: Can't you configure that in [`DbContext.OnModelCreating`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.onmodelcreating?view=efcore-2.1)?

Comment: I thought about that at first, then the problem is that the schema name is materialized into the migrations files. The way to specify the schema name is builder.HasDefaultSchema("schemaName"), which gets hard coded in the migrations files (with Add-Migration MigrationName). To my knowledge, there is no hook that would allow to pass a function that would return a schema name (in this case, per-tenant).

Comment: Looks like it's not a good idea https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/72